# Assembling MULS instruction on ARM with gcc and as

Tags: gcc, assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I have the following instruction in an assembly file:

```
MULS R0, R0, R2
```

This assembles fine using gcc (gcc -o prog pros.s) and the program works.
When I use as to assemble (as -o prog.o pros.s) I get:

```
Rd and Rm should be different in mul
```

Any idea why?

Comment: I believe this rule existed for core implementation (read bug or feature) on the early cores, but if you use a latter core I dont think that matters, read the architectural reference manual.  And what core are you calling out on the command line?   is it defaulting to armv4t?

Comment: Specifying the same register for <Rd> and <Rm> was previously described as producing UNPREDICTABLE results. There is no restriction in ARMv6, and it is believed all relevant ARMv4 and ARMv5 implementations do not require this restriction either, because high performance multipliers read all their operands prior to writing back any results.

Comment: thats from the arm arm

Comment: so that implies armv4 and armv5 have the issue, armv6 and armv7 dont

Comment: @old_timer, good question as I haven't specified a core for the gcc call. This is code being built on an Rpi running a 32-bit debian is, so AFAIK should be armv8. Ref manual doesn't seem to specify either way that the registers have to be different. I ran the gcc program using GDB, and disassembled the code, came up with the MULS mnemonic.

Comment: armv8 doesnt have r0,r1,... registers its an armv7 compatibility mode afaik so that aarch32 stuff would be there.  Either way those are well after this problem so your gcc is perhaps defaulting to armv4t (which is the default if you dont specify when you build gcc at least when I build it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably gcc uses a different default for thumb vs. ARM mode, or a default CPU architecture version.  Use `gcc -v` to see what it passes to `as`.

http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289882394.htm says Rd and Rn must be different for ARM before ARMv6.

But `muls` in thumb mode is only available at all as a 32-bit Thumb2 instruction in  ARMv6T2, so it always supports using the same register as destination and first source.  So assembling in Thumb mode means this form is always allowed.

If you want to assemble in ARM mode, you could use `as -march=armv7` or something to tell it the target CPU is ARMv7 (and thus doesn't need to avoid using the same register.)

IDK if you can set some of that stuff with assembler directives in the source, too.

Comment: Turns out gcc was defaulting to ARMv6, while as was going for ARMv4.  By setting as -march=armv8-a it assembled fine.

Answer (score 5):

From the ARM ARM

Specifying the same register for  and  was previously described as producing UNPREDICTABLE results. There is no restriction in ARMv6, and it is believed all relevant ARMv4 and ARMv5 implementations do not require this restriction either, because high performance multipliers read all their operands prior to writing back any results

ARMv4 and ARMv5 have this rule/issue, think bug, not feature.  ARMv6 and ARMv7 do not have this issue, so check the cpu/arch setting you are using when compiling and more importantly what target you are using.

Comment: the armv7 had some other interesting language related to one of the registers, I didnt understand off hand, may go back and read.   ARM ARM means ARM architectural reference manual, for some reason, which is unusual for them the ARMv7-AR did not mention this ARMv4/5 thing, but always good to just check so what they call the armv5 reference manual had the above, the armv7 has something else, armv8 is aarch64 and the aarch32 is an armv7 compatibility mode so the armv5 and armv7 ARM are where you would look for these things infocenter.arm.com may have to give up an email address